# Images aspect ratio distorted when making 100% height/width of container

Tags: css

I have this style:

```css
.album-photos-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: center;

  .image-card-small {
    width: 48%;
    margin: 4px;
    filter: brightness(0.8);
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      max-height: 400px;
    }
  }
}
```

This is what it looks like with images getting distorted.

[image: screenshot]

I read about the `display: flex;` and `flex-flow: wrap;` and it looks this is what they do and I need some other approach maybe.

I try to set the `max-height: 400px;` to a higher value like 2000 then it looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Please advise: I want images to fill the box no matter how wide or tall the image is!

### UPDATE

Here is the component

```
import React from 'react'

const ClickablePhoto = (props) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={props.onClick} className="image-card-small">
      <img  src={props.src} id={props.id}  alt="album" />
    </div>
  )
}

export default ClickablePhoto
```

And I tried like this:

```
  return (
    <div onClick={props.onClick} style={{backgroundImage: 'url(' + require(`${props.src}`) + ') background-size: cover'} } >
      <img  src={props.src} id={props.id}  alt="album" />
    </div>
  )
```

But the image src from the props looks like this: `/static/media/0_sJ1A5jGwSm66KCdV.e2451a3a.png` and `background-image: url` cant find the image

Comment: try object-fit:cover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't crop images with `<img>` element.
You could use div with background-image:

```
<div class="image" style="background-image: url(...); background-size: cover;" />
```

Comment: Thanks but the image src looks like this:
`/static/media/0_sJ1A5jGwSm66KCdV.e2451a3a.png` and `background-image: url` cant find the image

Comment: You don't need to pass img into div. You made incorrect style on div. Make `style={{ backgroundImage: \`url(${props.src})\`, backgroundSize: 'cover' }}`

Comment: Thanks your the master :)

Comment: I'm learning but if I should instead have an Image carousel Component what would you recommend https://reactjsexample.com/tag/carousel/